# Altering a MySql table causes a key constraint fail

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to add a Foreign Key to my `table1`, using this query.

```
  ALTER TABLE `db`.`table1` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`field1` )
  REFERENCES `db`.`table2` (`id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

`table1.field1` should refer to `table2.id`, which are both `INT(11)`.

It fails with this error :

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-3f9_4c'>, CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_2` FOREIGN KEY (`field1`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Trying it in Workbench gives the previous error and another one which says `ERROR 1050: Table 'table1' already exists`, showing a `CREATE TABLE` query, as if it's trying to "recreate" the table!

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error (`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`) is referenced in the [MySQL FK Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

To add a reference between 2 tables the condition must fit for existing data.

That means if you say `table1.id = table2.id` then all ids of `table1` and `table2` must match together.

To solve that you have to eliminate or fix those rows that don't match. 
Example:

```
table1.id  |  table2.fk
   1       |       1      ok 
   2       |     null     error
   3       |       4      error if id 4 is not in table1
```